# Revit Custom Addin - Solution with one project or multiple projects?

Tags: c#, revit-api

At the beginning my Revit Addin had only one project in Visual Studio but with the time I added more and more projects and per project always a new Addin (*.addin file) was created.

My question here is: Is there a best practice for this? Does one make several individual projects or does it bring from the performance in Revit something if only one large Addin project make?

In summary:

- several *.dll and *.addin files
- a single *.dll and *.addin file
  as an addin?

Before I start to restructure my whole solution with several projects into one project, I wanted to ask if there are any advantages or disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are advantages and disadvantages. For an extreme example and some sample code that you can use if you want to decide to go for the single DLL and add-in manifest solution, take a look at the RvtSamples Revit SDK sample:

- [Revit Developer Centre](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/revit)
- [The Building Coder on RvtSamples](https://www.google.com/search?q=RvtSamples&as_sitesearch=thebuildingcoder.typepad.com)

I implemented it as an external application. On startup, it reads one single text file listing over a hundred DLLs containing external command implementations and populates a menu with all of them grouped into different categories. When you click on a menu entry, the corresponding external command is loaded and executed.

Here is a log of some of the development steps. For your specific requirements, you may want to pay particular attention to the include file idea:

- [Loading SDK Samples](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/09/loading-sdk-sam.html)
- [Loading The Building Coder Samples](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/11/loading-the-building-coder-samples.html)
- [Porting the Building Coder Samples](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/05/porting-the-building-coder-samples.html)
- [Debugging with Visual Studio 2010 and RvtSamples](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/04/debugging-with-visual-studio-2010-and-rvtsamples.html)
- [Migrating the Building Coder Samples to Revit 2012](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/04/migrating-the-building-coder-samples-to-revit-2012.html)
- [Compiling the Revit 2014 SDK](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/04/compiling-the-revit-2014-sdk.html)
- [RvtSamples for Revit 2017](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/04/rvtsamples-for-revit-2017.html)
- [The Building Coder Samples 2017](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/05/the-building-coder-samples-2017.html)
- [Close Doc and Zero Doc RvtSamples](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/close-doc-and-zero-doc-rvtsamples.html)